# How to prove that $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} } | \frac{\sin( n)}{n} | $ diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It is stated as a problem in Spivak's Calculus and I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: The most promising thing I've tried is picking n so that $| \sin n | > x$, where x is some number between 0 and 1. Then we have that my original series is larger than something SIMILAR to the harmonic series. To be exact, harmonic series without those n where $| \sin n | \leq x$. Intuitively, we should be able to pick x so that those n are ''rare enough'', but I can't prove it rigorously.

Comment: Hint: for each $k\in\Bbb N$, the interval  $[k\pi+{\pi\over 6},(k+1)\pi-{\pi\over 6}]$  contains an integer. Using this and the comparison test, show that some subseries of your series diverges.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Hint:** $|\sin n|\geqslant \sin^2 n$, and use the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\color{red}2n)}n$ and the divergence of harmonic series.

We have $\cos(2n)=2\cos^2n-1$, and 
$$\sin^2n=1-\cos^2n=1-\frac{\cos(2n)+1}2=\frac{1-\cos(2n)}2.$$

Answer (score 12):

The idea in your comment leads to one approach:

For each positive integer $k$, the interval $\bigl[k\pi+{\pi\over 6}, (k+1)\pi-{\pi\over 6}\bigr]$ has length exceeding $1$ and thus contains an integer $n_k$. We then have ${|\sin (n_k)|\over n_k} \ge {\sin({\pi\over 6})\over (k+1)\pi}$.
So, from the Comparison test, it follows that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty  {|\sin(n_k)|\over n_k}$ diverges; whence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  {|\sin(n )|\over n}$ diverges (by the Comparison test again).

Comment: @David Mitra: how did you choose this specific interval($[\pi k +\frac{\pi}{6},\pi(k+1)-\frac{\pi}{6}$?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach. Assuming that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\left|\sin n\right|}{n}$ is convergent, [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma) ensures that $\{\left|\sin n\right|\}_{n\geq 1}$ has mean zero. Now there are at least a couple of ways  (besides $\left|\sin n\right|\geq \sin^2 n$) for showing this is absurd:

1. By the [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem), $e^{in}$ essentially is a random point on $S^1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence $\left|\sin n\right|$ essentially behaves like a random variable, whose density is supported on $(0,1)$ and given by $\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$;
2. The Fourier cosine series of $\left|\sin x\right|$ is given by
   $$ \left|\sin x\right|=\color{red}{\frac{2}{\pi}}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2mx)}{4m^2-1} $$
   hence the average value of $\{\left|\sin n\right|\}_{n\geq 1}$ is $\frac{2}{\pi}>0$.