# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ converge conditionally?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I think that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(n)}{n}$$ converges conditionally, but I´m not able to prove it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: **Hint**: Use [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264980/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-in-mathbbn-frac-sin-nn-diverges/264989) to see why it doesn't converge absolutely.

Comment: You are right !

Comment: http://cazelais.disted.camosun.bc.ca/250/dirichlet.pdf

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question in @DavidMitra's link. That question is a subset of this question, which requires one to show convergence of the sum without absolute values.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct that your series converges:

So you need to use [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), which you might be somewhat familiar with, in that the **alternating series test** is a *particular* case of the Dirichlet's Test. This includes a checklist of three conditions for a series like yours, which if satisfied, reveal the series is *convergent*. You just need to *show that your series meets those conditions*, and your conclusion follows.

Added: there is a corollary to the Dirichlet's test that tells that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin n$$ converges whenever $\,\{a_n\}\,$ is a decreasing sequence that tends to zero. And indeed, in your case $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n},$$ we have that $a_n = \dfrac 1n$, which we know is a decreasing sequence which tends to zero as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: I wouldn't call Dirichlet's Test the "alternating series test". This last test is a particular case of Dirichlet's.

Comment: Yes, @Peter, I was actually returning to the question to make that distinction. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, no. Dirichlet's Test doesn't talk about conditional convergence, just convergence. Or are you saying something else in "This includes a checklist of three conditions for a series like yours, which if satisfied, reveal the series is conditionally convergent."?

Comment: Got your back, Jack =)

Comment: You did not answer the question.  Is the convergence conditional?  You need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fourier series calculations it follows 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n x)}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}
$$
for every $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. Your sum is $\frac{\pi-1}{2}$.